# When I click on StiMvcViewer bar to go to next page everything disapear

Tags: asp.net-mvc, report, stimulsoft

I am going to design a report to print bill for houses. each record in one A4 page. I design the report in Stimulsoft designer and call it from asp.net mvc. so far every think is ok and i can see first A4 page that shows first bill. but when I click on next page button or any other buttons on the bar such as zoom, print...
everything disappear.
I really appreciate if anyone can help me.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaDmR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did not add the ViewerEvent action. It's necessary.

```
@Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(
"MvcViewer1", new StiMvcViewerOptions() {
  Actions =
  { 
    GetReportSnapshot = "GetReportSnapshot",
    ViewerEvent = "ViewerEvent"
  }
})
```

Look at the [Stimulsoft Programming Manual](http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/programming-manual/using_mvc_viewer_showing_reports.htm)